# How can I save a given Activity's current layout when opening another?

Tags: android

I've been looking around for help on this, and haven't been able to find anything that actually explains it. I'm fairly new to Android programming, and I'm working on my first app, a score keeper for a card game.

In `MainActivity`, I have an `ImageButton` that, when pressed, prompts the user to enter in the number of players and the players' names. Once this is done, the app programmatically fills out a `TableLayout` with a grid of `TextView`s that will hold the scores. It makes the `ImageButton` and associated `TextView` disappear, and makes the `TableLayout` visible. However, when the user goes to one of two Activities in the menu, then clicks on the up arrow to go back to `MainActivity` (I call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` on both Activities), `MainActivity` reverts back to the original layout (as if the user had just opened the app). This is not the case, however, when the user returns to `MainActivity` via the device back button.

I know that I can't rely on `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` for this, since those are only called if the system destroys the Activity (At least, that is my understanding. Correct me if I'm wrong). From what I've gathered, if I want to save and reload the current layout, I need to do it in `onPause()` and `onResume()`, but I am not sure of a good way to do this since I can't effectively use a `Bundle`. Is there a good way to go about this?

Comment: You should consider creating a new activity rather than just changing the layout of the existing one.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'll look into that. That would be smart. As I mentioned, I'm fairly new to Android development, so I'm open to anything that would improve my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android programming, there are two standard ways of changing screens:

1. Create an Activity for each screen and switch screens by choosing the correct Activity with an Intent.
2. Create a Fragment for each screen and use the FragmentManager to switch screens.

The [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/index.html) has tutorials about both of these. It also has resources on just about everything you need to know about making an Android app. You should definitely familiarize yourself with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment instead. when you try to open another, just hide current fragment and show/add another fragment